# Template deduction and function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

How does the compiler know the correct type for this code:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    typedef View * ViewType;
    typedef boost::function<ViewType ()> ActionType;
    typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, ActionType> ActionMapType;

    ActionMapType actions;

    template <class ControllerType>
    inline void addAction(std::string actionName, ViewType (ControllerType::*action)()) { actions.insert(ActionMapType::value_type(actionName, bind<ViewType>(&action, static_cast<ControllerType *>(this)))); }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    Derived()
    {
        addAction("someAction", &Derived::foo); // No template
    }

    ViewType foo() { cout << "foo"; }
}
```

I am aware that I am passing Derived as ControllerType but how can the compiler know for sure that Derived is the template parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template parameter is `ControllerType` which is used in the function parameter list as `ViewType (ControllerType::*action)()` parameter. When you supply an actual argument of `ViewType (Derived::*)()` type, the compiler immediately realizes that `ControllerType = Derived`. That's it. This is called template argument deduction.

In some contexts in C++ the compiler cannot deduce the template argument from the type of function argument. Such contexts are called *non-deduced contexts*. The language specification provides a list of non-deduced contexts. And yours is not one of them.

Comment: That I already got. I was asking for why that happened. See Bruce's answer.

Comment: You mean, you know how template argument deduction works, but you don't know that template argument deduction exists?

Comment: I knew that template deduction can happen, I didn't actually know when. When it worked I guessed it had something to do with the function pointer but I wasn't sure. Also I wasn't aware that template argument deduction exists.

Answer (score 1):

Function templates will deduce their types.

You have `ViewType (ControllerType::*action)()`, where `ControllerType` can be any class. So basically it's looking for a pointer to a class function that takes nothing and returns a `ViewType` and the class can be any class. The "any type" must be `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

It knows `Derived` is the template parameter because you specified `&Derived::foo` (and not, say, `&SomethingElse::foo`) in the `addAction()` function call.  This is determined at compile time, so no RTTI is needed.